# Appium Inspector failed

Tags: android, macos, appium

I'm trying to connect appium to genymotion emulator. In Appium.app (Mac os x) when I click inspector button it throws an error like below :

```
  Could not start a new session

        Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by
     using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and 
    activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying 
    this in the desired capabilities object.
```

[image]

Comment: This is probably better suited for another Stack Exchange site like http://superuser.com/.

Comment: I solved this right now

Comment: Then post the answer before it gets flagged

Comment: I forgot to fix java android path .